Can I use a single GTM variable which contains an object or array to create multiple tag variables?
I have a custom javascript variable in Google Tag Manager which returns a set of data from session storage in an object like this:
{"companySize":"100","industry":"Manufacturing","jobRole":"Manager","etc":"etc"}
Is it possible to use this single variable to create multiple variables within in a tag?
For example:
{{object variable}}.companySize? Or do I have to make multiple individual variables in GTM to capture the value of each element separately?
I have tried to to this in both an array format {{object variable}}[0] as well as in an object reference format {{object variable}}.companySize - both return something that looks like "[object Object].companySize" in GTM preview mode instead of the value targeted.

You can do that in code, but not in UI.
So if you reference your object returning variable in a custom html tag, or in a custom JS variable, then yes, of course you can manipulate the object. Whenever you reference vairables in the UI, however, they will be almost always be cast to string. And when you cast an object to string in JS, you'll get [object Object] Here to demonstrate:

So when you try poking at that object in UI by adding .property it just concats it to the [object Object] string, which is what you see in the preview.
So yes, multiple GTM variables. But hey, given how limited GA's custom dimensions are, it's not that much work to make a GTM variable for each, plus it allows you to add a layer of logic in case you need to change something for a particular dimension.
